# Set edgecolor on seaborn jointplot

Tags: python, seaborn, jointplot

I am able to set edgecolors for a seaborn histogram by passing in a hist_kws argument:

```
sns.distplot(ad_data["Age"], kde = False, bins = 35, hist_kws = {"ec":"black"})
```

However, I'm unable to similarly set edgecolors for the histograms in a seaborn jointplot. It doesn't accept a hist_kws argument or any other similar argument to set edgecolors. I'm unable to find anything in the document that addresses this. Any help would be appreciated.

For reference, I'm using seaborn 0.9 and matplotlib 3.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a 'hist_kws' inside the 'marginal_kws':

```py
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.random.normal(np.repeat([2, 8, 7, 10], 1000), 1)
y = np.random.normal(np.repeat([7, 2, 9, 4], 1000), 1)

g = sns.jointplot(x=x, y=y, color='purple', alpha=0.1,
                  marginal_kws={'color': 'tomato', 'hist_kws': {'edgecolor': 'black'}})
plt.show()
```

[image: example plot]

In this case, [`jointplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.jointplot.html) sends the `marginal_kws` to [`distplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.distplot.html) which in its turn sends the `hist_kws` to matplotlib's [`hist`](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.0/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.hist.html).

Similarly, you can also set the parameters of a `kde` for the `distplot`:

```
g = sns.jointplot(x=x, y=y, kind='hex', color='indigo', 
                  marginal_kws={'color': 'purple', 'kde': True,
                                'kde_kws': {'color': 'crimson', 'lw': 1},
                                'hist_kws': {'ec': 'black', 'lw': 2}})
```